# Creating a second solution for a specialized project gives: "The project could not be loaded. Could not find file..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We have a large solution containing many projects - I am trying to create a sub-set solution containing a single project but am running into a roadblock where VS is ignoring my path.  I would like to retain the same solution path to prevent duplicate build steps which reference the solution folder.

D:\Dev\Sol1\Sol1.sln - contains N projects in subfolders.
- For example: D:\Dev\Sol1\Prj1\Prj1.csproj

When I create D:\Dev\Sol2\Sol2.sln, I can reference any of Sol1's projects, using ..\Sol1\Prj1\Prj1.csproj

If I move it to D:\Dev\Sol1\Sol2.sln, VS gives me the error:

> The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file
>   'D:\Dev\Soln1\Prj1.csproj'

Notice that it is ignoring the subfolder structure entirely.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I made a merge where projects were added on both branches. After all paths and counts were fixed inside sln, there still was a problem with "The project could not be loaded. Could not find file… " + very strange, never existing paths.

The resolution that worked: delete solution's suo file (personal settings cached project info and it caused the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `.sln` file and update the paths to the projects.

Comment: The paths are correct as far as I can tell "..\Sol1\Prj1\Prj1.csproj" as above.  I have also tried changing to ".\Prj1\Prj1.csproj" when in the Sol2 folder - same result.